# Is it recommended to use jQuery method in AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is it recommended to use jQuery method in AngularJS controller?

If not, how should i convert to AngularJS below?

I know I can use directive but I need a clean and simple way.

```
$scope.onEnabled = function (id, enabled) {

    if (enabled) {
        jQuery('#policyRuleTitle-' + id).removeClass('collapsed');
        jQuery('#policyRule-' + id).addClass('in');
        jQuery('#policyRule-' + id).css("height", "");
    } else {
        jQuery('#policyRuleTitle-' + id).addClass('collapsed');
        jQuery('#policyRule-' + id).removeClass('in');
    }
};
```

Comment: use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), you don't need jQuery for that

Comment: Indeed ng-class is the way to go, and for the css part you could use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not recommended for this kind of usage as you can do it easily entirely in AngularJS.

Here is a good starting point:

```
<div id="#policyRuleTitle" ng-class="{ collapsed: enable }"></div>
<div id="#policyRule" ng-class="{ in: enable }"></div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: I need to remove the style 'height' attribute too. jQuery('#policyRule-' + id).css("height", ""); How can it be done with ng-style? I can't seems to allow a condition

Comment: Just like with `ng-class`: `ng-style="{ height: your_condition ? your_height : auto }"`

Comment: I need the height attribute to be removed from 'style'

Comment: You cannot remove the `height` attribute in HTML/CSS. But `auto` is its default value and that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Binary Brain answer, you can use "Directives" if you need to do complex DOM manipulations, or just anything that you can't achieve with the native directives and it's related to DOM manipulations.

You can create a custom directive and do there whatever you want with the DOM.

Read here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1):

**[Don't mix up JQuery with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542)**, Since its not a Good Practice,

If you want to change the class and style use in-built **[ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**, **[ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)** directive feature provided by AngularJS instead of using JQuery `.removeClass` and `.addClass`.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ydmjwzfp/)**

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.areaStatus = true;
  $scope.enabled = false;
  $scope.myStyle = {
    'height': '0px'
  }
  $scope.onEnabled = function() {
    if ($scope.enabled) {
      $scope.areaStatus = true;
      $scope.myStyle = {
        'height': '0px'
      }
      $scope.enabled = !$scope.enabled
    } else {
      $scope.areaStatus = false;
      $scope.myStyle = {
        'height': '50px'
      }
      $scope.enabled = !$scope.enabled
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.in {
  color: red;
}
.collapsed {
  color: green;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="onEnabled()" ng-model="myButton">Toggle</button>
    <div ng-style="myStyle" ng-class="{'in' : !areaStatus, 'collapsed' : areaStatus}">This is some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to remove the style 'height' attribute too.
jQuery('#policyRule-' + id).css("height", ""); How can it be done with ng-style? I can't seems to allow a condition

Comment: @in_visible take a look at my update.....now when class `in` is added height is added and when `collapsed` is added height is removed

Comment: @in_visible i guess this is what you want....same at http://jsfiddle.net/1wecv84x/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is with ng-class and ng-style.
You will find an example here:
http://jsbin.com/firosoleba/1/edit

```
<div id="testAngular" ng-controller="mycontroller">

    <div ng-class="div_class">Div Element</div>
    <div ng-style="{'background-color':'yellow'}">Colored Div Element</div>

</div>
```

and

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])
.controller('mycontroller',
    ["$scope",
    function($scope){

      $scope.div_class = "myDivClass"
      $scope.div_css = "{'background-color':'yellow'}"

    }]);
```